# CGI Script Behaving Mysteriously on a thttpd server

Tags: html, c, linux, file, cgi

I just can't figure out why the output of CGI script is unstable despite the input being same in all run.

I have this CGI script[in C], Which generate an `html` page which has a table that reproduces the tree/hierarchical view of filesystem(Ubuntu).it is run on arm-platform and is mini(developed with lighthttpd).So the o/p of script is a table filled with directory names and file names. My problem is it list the filesystem(list of files and folders) in that table successfully when run, say now and it doesn't display the table with files and folders when run say after 10 mins or so, keeping the input same(filesystem and files still the same)[ Browser just displays error message `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.`
Or a blank page.]

What might be the problem??I have run the script on server and verified the output being a valid HTML Page with paths to files and folders valid and they all exist. But the same script some times displays the table successfully, other wise any of those errors I mentioned above. I doubt this might be related to permission issue, but if so, how is it displaying it occasionally? I have changed the permission of all files and folders which I am processing to full.But still doesn't help!!:(

The script is as follows...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  int dir_count = 0;
  int file_count = 0;
  int dir_index=0;
  int file_index=0;
  int inner_loop=0;
  int len=0;
  int i=0;
  DIR * dirp;
  DIR * dirp2;
  DIR * dirp3;
  char realbase[35]="/home";
  char final_report_path[30];
  char base[20];
  char source[20];
  char patient_id[15];
  char patient_name[15];
  int j=0;
  struct dirent * entry;
  char dir_name[500][20];
  char* file_name[500];
  dirp = opendir(realbase); 
  if(dirp)
  while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) 
    {
             if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) 
        { /* If the entry is a regular file */
                 if(entry->d_name[0]!='.' && entry->d_name[1]!='.')
            {
                 dir_count++;
                         strcpy(dir_name[dir_index++],entry->d_name);

            }
            }
    }
  closedir(dirp);
  printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
  printf("<html>\n");
  printf("<body>\n");
  printf("<h1>Blah Blah!!</h1>\n");
  printf("\n");
  printf("    \n");
  printf("Click on the links to view Reports\n");
  printf("    \n");
  printf("<table border=\"3\" bordercolor=\"#c86260\" bgcolor=\"#ffffcc\" width=\"50%\" cellspacing=\"5\" cellpadding=\"3\">\n");
  printf("<tr><td><b>Patient Name</b></td><td><b>Patient ID</b></td><td><b>Reports</b></td></tr>\n");
  for(i=0;i<dir_count;i++)
  {
   strncpy(source, "", sizeof(source));
   strncpy(base, "", sizeof(base));
   strncpy(patient_name, "", sizeof(patient_name));
   strncpy(patient_id, "", sizeof(patient_id));
   strcpy(source,dir_name[i]);
   if(source[0]!='.')
{
   strcpy(base,"/home");
                      for(len=0;len<sizeof(source);len++)
                    {
                        if(source[len]!='_')
                        patient_name[len]=source[len];
                        else
                        {
                                                len++;

                        break;
                        }
                    }
                 for(inner_loop=0;len<sizeof(source);len++,inner_loop++)
                    {
                        if(source[len]!='\0')
                        patient_id[inner_loop]=source[len];
                        else
                        {

                        break;
                        }
                    }
   printf("<tr><td valign=\"center\">%s</td>",patient_name);
   printf("<td valign=\"center\">%s</td>",patient_id);

   strcat(base,source);
   strcat(base,"/Reports/");

   dirp2 = opendir(base); 
   if(dirp2)
   while ((entry = readdir(dirp2)) != NULL) 
    {

             if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) 
        { /* If the entry is a regular file */
                 if(entry->d_name[0]!='.')
            {
                                 if(file_count==0)
                                 {
                                  printf("<td>");
                                 }
                                 if(file_count!=0)
                                 {
                                  printf("<br>");
                                 }
                 file_count++;
                         file_name[file_index++]=entry->d_name;

                 printf("<a href=\"/home/%s/Reports/%s\">",dir_name[i],file_name[file_index-1]);
                 printf("%s",file_name[file_index-1]);
                 printf("</a>");
            }
            }
    }
   if(file_count>0)
   printf("</td>");
   printf("</tr>\n");
   file_count=0;
   file_index=0;
   closedir(dirp2);
}
  }

  printf("</table>");

  printf("</body>\n");
  printf("</html>\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This sounds as if it's a small CGI program. Could you post the code? Or a small version that replicates the problem?

Comment: I have added the entire code.Its so simple code.

Comment: You do some funky stuff: `strcpy(dir_name[dir_index++],entry->d_name);` This is copied into a space that is allocated to 20 bytes, as far as I can see, without any checks. I'd suggest running this with `valgrind` in an interactive environment to get rid of potential problems where you write garbage into your variables.

Comment: But how is it getting run successfully at some runs and not in all? I still didn't get what's wrong with using strcpy(dir_name[dir_index++],entry->d_name);..You saying only names under 20 bytes length can be copied?

Comment: If you copy data without checking for length and use input that's not controlled in any way, you might overwrite your variables or your stack or something equally nasty. So, it might just be luck that it works from time to time, depending on what happens to be on the stack when you run it. Always check for length or, better, limit the amount of bytes that are to be copied to some safe amount. Then you KNOW what will happen even if the input data is weird.

Comment: ok, let me try!Thanx for the response:)